# How do you use alias multiple times in MySql?

Tags: mysql, alias

I want to use this code in `mysql` but don't know how to make it work:

```
SELECT 
        no1 + no2 + no3 as 'total',
        'total' - no4 as 'arr', 
        (('total')+('arr')) * 2 / 100) as 'net'

FROM table
```

It shows correct result but I want a compressed form using an alias that I can access multiple times:

```
SELECT
       no1+ no2 +no3 as 'total', 
       (no1+ no2 +no3) - no4 as 'arr',
       ((no1+ no2 +no3) - 'no4') * 2 / 100 as 'per',
       ((no1+ no2 +no3) - 'no4') + (((no1+ no2 +no3) - 'no4') * 2 / 100) as 'net'
FROM table
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html 
Specifically `the column value may not yet have been determined`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: it's not possible.

A quote from the [`documentation`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html):

> A *select_expr* can be given an alias using `AS alias_name`. The alias is used as the expression's column name and can be used in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses.

I think an alias cannot be used in a `SELECT` expression to avoid circular dependencies and invalid references (when the aliased expression contains an [aggregate GROUP BY function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html), f.e.).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html), not alias, some like this:

`Select 
        @total := no1 + no2 + no3 ,
        @arr := @total - no4, 
        @net := (((@total)+(@arr)) * 2 / 100)
from table`